# How to Change Permission of the Folder and all child of That folder

Tags: macos, permissions, prestashop-1.5

I'm Trying to install `Prestashop` in my Localhost in `Mac OSX` but all of the Folder Permission is `"Not Access"` so I should Change the each folders permission to Full Access.

But I'm looking easier way to do it because i Should change 20+ folder&File permission.
So

**how to change Permission of the Folder and  all child of That folder**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

to change Permission of the Folder and all child of That folder :

Click On The "gear" Icon and Select The **Apply To Enclosed Item**

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Personally, I would try to edit the folder permissions on a trial-and-error basis. If that does not work, it is probably something a little deeper than folder permissions.

Changing File Permissions

This is the most user friendly way to adjust file permissions in OS X:

- Select the file or app in the Finder you want to edit permissions for
- Hit Command+i to “Get Info” about the selected file (or go to File >
  Get Info)
- At the bottom of the Get Info window, you’ll see “Sharing &
  Permissions”, select the arrow to drop down the options
- Adjust permissions on a per user basis, the options being: read and
  write, read only, or no access

Source: http://osxdaily.com/2011/02/21/change-file-permissions-mac/